# Visual Studio 2010 Crash on project/form load

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

First i want to apologize for my english :S.

Hi i just got visual studio pro 2 days ago and every time i create a project, close VS 2010 and when i come back to work on my project and i click on my Form.vb i got every time : `Visual Studio has stopped working`.Then i tried run as administrator it doesn't work. What i don't understand it's when i click on show code the form load but the moment i click on it ,it just crashing and it's make me wanna drop laptop cascade...I've look on forum and post here but i haven't saw what i was searching.

Here the error that VS show me :(Those files doesn't exist i search)

> ```
> Files that help describe the problem: 
>   C:\Users\Usager\AppData\Local\Temp\WER152.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml
>   C:\Users\Usager\AppData\Local\Temp\WER18C9.tmp.appcompat.txt
>   C:\Users\Usager\AppData\Local\Temp\WER3520.tmp.hdmp
> An unhandle win32 exception occured in devenv.exe[1688]
>
> Unhandled exception at 0x777715de in devenv.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading 
> location 0x00000000.
> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ExecutionEngineException' occurred in
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.dll
> ```

Again thank you for your time to helping me.**

**Here the Error log :
[02/07/12,18:22:19] Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - FRA: [2] UpdateFileFetcherFromMsi: Warning: Missing fwlink entry for cabinet: #GDR.cab
[02/07/12,18:22:19] Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - FRA: [2] UpdateFileFetcherFromMsi: Warning: Missing fwlink entry for cabinet: #QFE.cab
[02/07/12,18:55:04] VS70pgui: [2] Return for Visual Studio 2010 Tools pour SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP2 FRA indicates a failed installation. DepCheck indicates the component is installed.
[02/07/12,18:57:05] Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - FRA: [2] UpdateFileFetcherFromMsi: Warning: Missing fwlink entry for cabinet: #GDR.cab
[02/07/12,18:57:05] Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - FRA: [2] UpdateFileFetcherFromMsi: Warning: Missing fwlink entry for cabinet: #QFE.cab
[02/07/12,19:15:44] Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - FRA: [2] UpdateFileFetcherFromMsi: Warning: Missing fwlink entry for cabinet: #GDR.cab
[02/07/12,19:15:44] Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - FRA: [2] UpdateFileFetcherFromMsi: Warning: Missing fwlink entry for cabinet: #QFE.cab
***EndOfSession***

Answer (score 2):

Could be the *.suo file next to the .sln file. Delete it and retry?

See [this](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/657195/visual-studio-2010-crashes-when-suo-files-get-corrupted) for more info

Comment: Try but it keep crashing i keep my error log i don't know if it could

Comment: Couldnt figure out what was going on, very frustrating, this worked for me, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error. I found out that the destination path had too many characters and was too long.   I fixed it by moving the whole project to my main drive (C:).